# AWS Lambda using Winston logging loses Request ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, winston, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When using `console.log` to add log rows to AWS CloudWatch, the Lambda Request ID is added on each row as [described in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html)

A simplified example based on the above mentioned doc

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
  console.log("Hello");
  return context.logStreamName
};
```

Would produce output such as

> START RequestId: c793869b-ee49-115b-a5b6-4fd21e8dedac Version: $LATEST
>
> 2019-06-07T19:11:20.562Z  c793869b-ee49-115b-a5b6-4fd21e8dedac INFO Hello
>
> END RequestId: c793869b-ee49-115b-a5b6-4fd21e8dedac
>
> REPORT RequestId: c793869b-ee49-115b-a5b6-4fd21e8dedac    Duration: 170.19 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB

The relevant detail here regarding this question is the Request ID, `c793869b-ee49-115b-a5b6-4fd21e8dedac` which is added after the timestamp on the row with "Hello".

The AWS documentation states

> To output logs from your function code, you can use methods on the console object, or any logging library that writes to stdout or stderr.
>
> The Node.js runtime logs the START, END, and REPORT lines for each invocation, and adds a timestamp, request ID, and log level to each entry logged by the function.

When using Winston as a logger, the Request ID is lost. Could be an issued with formatters or transports. The logger is created like

```
const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: combine(
      timestamp(),
      printf(
        ({ timestamp, level, message }) => `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`
      )
    ),
    transports: [new transports.Console()]
  });
```

I also tried `simple()` formatter instead of `printf()`, but that has no effect on whether Request ID is present or not. Also removing formatting altogether still prints the plain text, i.e. no timestamp or request id.

I also checked the source code of Winston Console transport, and it uses either `console._stdout.write` if present, or `console.log` for writing, which is what the AWS documentation said to be supported.

**Is there some way to configure Winston to keep the AWS Lambda Request ID as part of the message?**

P.S. There are separate Winston Transports for AWS CloudWatch that I am aware of, but they require other setup functionality that I'd like to avoid if possible. And since the Request ID is readily available, they seem like an overkill.

P.P.S. Request ID can also be fetched from Lambda Context and custom logger object initialized with it, but I'd like to also avoid that, pretty much for the same reasons: extra work for something that should be readily available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the usage of `console._stdout.write()` / `process._stdout.write()`, which Winston built-in Console Transport uses when present.

For some reason lines written to stdout go to CloudWatch as is, and timestamp/request ID are not added to log rows as they are with `console.log()` calls.

There is a [discussion on Github about making this a constructor option](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/981) that could be selected on transport creation, but it was closed as a problem related to specific IDEs and how they handle stdout logs. The issue with AWS Lambdas is mentioned only as a side note in the discussion.

My solution was to make a custom transport for Winston, which always uses `console.log()` to write the messages and leave timestamp and request ID to be filled in by AWS Lambda Node runtime.

**Addition 5/2020:**
Below is an examples of my solution. Unfortunaly I cannot remember much of the details of this implementation, but I pretty much looked at [Winston sources in Github](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/console.js) and took the bare minimum implementation and forced use of `console.log`

```js
'use strict';

const TransportStream = require('winston-transport');

class SimpleConsole extends TransportStream {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.name = options.name || 'simple-console';
  }

  log(info, callback) {
    setImmediate(() => this.emit('logged', info));

    const MESSAGE = Symbol.for('message');
    console.log(info[MESSAGE]);

    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }
};

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: combine(
    printf(({ level, message }) => `${level.toUpperCase()}: ${message}`)
  ),
  transports: [new SimpleConsole()]
});

const debug = (...args) => logger.debug(args);
// ... And similar definition to other logging levels, info, warn, error etc

module.exports = {
  debug
  // Also export other logging levels..
};
```

**Another option**

As pointed out by @sanrodari in the comments, the same can be achieved by directly overriding the log method in built-in Console transport and force the use of `console.log`.

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      log(info, callback) {
        setImmediate(() => this.emit('logged', info));

        if (this.stderrLevels[info[LEVEL]]) {
          console.error(info[MESSAGE]);

          if (callback) {
            callback();
          }
          return;
        }

        console.log(info[MESSAGE]);

        if (callback) {
          callback();
        }
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

See [full example for more details](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1305#issuecomment-387634897)

Comment: is this still the preferred way of handling the issue?

Comment: I haven't tested AWS logging without this workaround. As I understand Winston is not changing as in their view the problem is not in the logging library. Also some comments on Github stated that console.log is slower than process._stdout and the like. CloudWatch does this async AFAIK, so no need to worry about the speed probably. TL;DR; If AWS has changed and supports  better the stdout approach it could work. Otherwise wrap in custom transport or check libs mentioned in the question. If you get it working without hacks, please post back and let others know as well.

Comment: my guess is that that the lambda runtime overloads the console object to add this info...

Comment: @kaskelotti could you share your custom transport?

Comment: @Jason I updated the answer and added the custom transport and how it is used.

Comment: I found what I think might be a better solution to this problem: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1305#issuecomment-387634897

Comment: @sanrodari if you can verify that the solution works with AWS CloudWatch, I can add it to my answer. Or if you wish, you can make another answer with the details. Functionally it's pretty much the same as mine, but it's shorter and thus maybe more readable.

Comment: @kaskelotti yes, I can confirm, screenshot: https://imgur.com/AlcacVZ. Can you please add it to your answer, I'm a little busy at the moment, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know OP said they would like to avoid using the Lambda context object to add the request ID, but I wanted to share my solution with others who may not have this requirement. While the other answers require defining a custom transport or overriding the log method of the Console transport, for this solution you just need to add one line to the top of your handler function.

```js
import { APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent, Callback, Context } from "aws-lambda";
import { createLogger, format, transports } from "winston";


const logger = createLogger({
  level: "debug",
  format: format.json({ space: 2 }),
  transports: new transports.Console()
});

export const handler = (
  event: APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent,
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback
): void => {

  // Add this line to add the requestId to logs
  logger.defaultMeta = { requestId: context.awsRequestId };

  logger.info("This is an example log message"); // prints:
  //  {
  //    "level": "info",
  //    "message": "This is an example log message",
  //    "requestId": "ac1de841-ca30-4a09-9950-dd4fe7e37af8"
  //  }
};
```

[Documentation for Lambda context object in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html)

For other Winston formats like `printf`, you will need to add the `requestId` property to the format string. Not only is this more concise, but it has the benefit of allowing you to customize where the request ID appears in your log output, rather than always prepending the request ID like CloudWatch does.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by @kaskelloti AWS does not transforms messages logged by `console._stdout.write()` and `console._stderr.write()`

here is my modified solution which respects levels in AWS logs

```js
const LEVEL = Symbol.for('level');
const MESSAGE = Symbol.for('message');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            log(logPayload, callback) {
                setImmediate(() => this.emit('logged', logPayload));
                const message = logPayload[MESSAGE]

                switch (logPayload[LEVEL]) {
                    case "debug":
                        console.debug(message);
                        break
                    case "info":
                        console.info(message);
                        break
                    case "warn":
                        console.warn(message);
                        break
                    case "error":
                        console.error(message);
                        break
                    default:
                        //TODO: handle missing levels
                        break
                }

                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        })
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html)

> To output logs from your function code, you can use methods on the console object, or any logging library that writes to stdout or stderr.

I ran a quick test using the following Winston setup in a lambda:

```
const path = require('path');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, errors, timestamp } = format;

const baseFormat = combine(
  timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
  errors({ stack: true }),
  format((info) => {
    info.level = info.level.toUpperCase();
    return info;
  })(),
);

const splunkFormat = combine(
  baseFormat,
  format.json(),
);

const prettyFormat = combine(
  baseFormat,
  format.prettyPrint(),
);

const createCustomLogger = (moduleName) => createLogger({
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
  format: process.env.PRETTY_LOGS ? prettyFormat : splunkFormat,
  defaultMeta: { module: path.basename(moduleName) },
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
  ],
});

module.exports = createCustomLogger;
```

and in CloudWatch, I am *NOT* getting my Request ID.  I am getting a timestamp from my own logs, so I'm less concerned about it.  Not getting the Request ID is what bothers me

[image]